# Count daily fidelity

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the below table and I would like to count, day by day, the number of distinct people who logged in everyday. For example, for day 1, everyone logged in, so it's 4. For day 4, there's just one person ID who logged in everyday since day 1, so the count would be 1.

| DAY | PERSON_ID |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 01 |
| 1 | 02 |
| 1 | 03 |
| 1 | 04 |
| 2 | 01 |
| 2 | 02 |
| 2 | 03 |
| 3 | 01 |
| 4 | 02 |
| 4 | 01 |

Expected output.

| DAY | PEOPLE_LOGGED_EVERYDAY | PEOPLE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 4 | 01, 02, 03, 04 |
| 2 | 3 | 01, 02, 03 |
| 3 | 1 | 01 |
| 4 | 1 | 01 |

EDIT: the query should also work on the below data.

```
with t ( DAY, PERSON_ID ) AS(
    SELECT 10, '01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 10, '02' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 10, '04' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 10, '04' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 12, '01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 12, '02' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 12, '03' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 13, '04' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 13, '01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 14, '02' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 14, '01' FROM DUAL)
```

Expected output:

| DAY | PEOPLE_LOGGED_EVERYDAY | PEOPLE | EXPLANATION |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | 3 | 01, 02, 04 | Three unique people in day 10 |
| 12 | 2 | 01, 02 | Day 11 does not have values, so it's not included. From those in day 10, only 2 appear in day 12 |
| 13 | 1 | 01 | From those in day 10 and 12, only 01 appears in day 13 |
| 14 | 1 | 01 | From those in day 10, 12 and 13, only 01 appears in day 14 |

Comment: how is people_logge_everday for day =2 have a vale of3?  Do not understand how you get the output it should be 1, no?

Comment: @OldProgrammer sorry, I mistyped the data. That´s it amended.

Comment: Regarding your update and "the query should also work on the below data." All the queries below produce an output for the new data so, in that sense, they all "work". What you have not said is how you expect them to work so your update is practically useless and would need to include the expected output for that data to have any value.

Comment: @MT0 I've now included expected output for my provided data.

Comment: How on day 10 is the count 4 when the people column only shows 3 people? Why on day 12 are there 3 people when there were 0 people on day 11? Why on day 12 is the count 3 when the people column shows 2? Please [edit] your question and explain **FULLY** the logic of how you expect the data to be counted.

Comment: @MT0 sorry, I forgot to update that column. I've also included a column in the output with the explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `listagg()` with `group by` clause. If day is always start from the 1 and increases by 1 then you can use below query. He with the help of `exits` I have selected only those person_id which are available in all the previous days.

```
 create table yourtable(DAY int, PERSON_ID varchar(10));

 insert into yourtable values(1,    '01');
 insert into yourtable values(1,    '02');
 insert into yourtable values(1,    '03');
 insert into yourtable values(1,    '04');
 insert into yourtable values(2,    '01');
 insert into yourtable values(2,    '02');
 insert into yourtable values(2,    '03');
 insert into yourtable values(3,    '01');
 insert into yourtable values(4,    '02');
 insert into yourtable values(4,    '01');
```

Query:

```
select day, count(person_id) as PEOPLE_LOGGED_EVERYDAY, LISTAGG(person_id,',') WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY person_id) AS PEOPLE
       from yourtable a
       where exists (select 1 from yourtable b where b.day<=a.day and a.person_id=b.person_id
       group by person_id having count(day)=a.day)
       group by day;
```

Output:

| DAY | PEOPLE_LOGGED_EVERYDAY | PEOPLE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 4 | 01,02,03,04 |
| 2 | 3 | 01,02,03 |
| 3 | 1 | 01 |
| 4 | 1 | 01 |

*db<fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=b048a717d72a995139a5399fb5f01ab6)*

Instead of day sequence if you had increasing dates in day column:

```
 create table yourtable(DAY date, PERSON_ID varchar(10));

 insert into yourtable values(date '2021-01-01',    '01');
 insert into yourtable values(date '2021-01-01',    '02');
 insert into yourtable values(date '2021-01-01',    '03');
 insert into yourtable values(date '2021-01-01',    '04');
 insert into yourtable values(date '2021-01-02',    '01');
 insert into yourtable values(date '2021-01-02',    '02');
 insert into yourtable values(date '2021-01-02',    '03');
 insert into yourtable values(date '2021-01-03',    '01');
 insert into yourtable values(date '2021-01-04',    '02');
 insert into yourtable values(date '2021-01-04',    '01');
```

Query:

```
   select day, count(person_id) as PEOPLE_LOGGED_EVERYDAY, LISTAGG(person_id,',') WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY person_id) AS PEOPLE
   from yourtable a
   where exists (select 1 from yourtable b where b.day<=a.day and a.person_id=b.person_id
   group by person_id having count(day)=( max(day)- min(day))+1)
   group by day;
```

Output:

| DAY | PEOPLE_LOGGED_EVERYDAY | PEOPLE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01-JAN-21 | 4 | 01,02,03,04 |
| 02-JAN-21 | 3 | 01,02,03 |
| 03-JAN-21 | 1 | 01 |
| 04-JAN-21 | 1 | 01 |

*db<fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=981e6340b8628519b06debb23da3c76c)*

**Revised answer**

```
 create table yourtable(DAY int, PERSON_ID varchar(10));

 insert into yourtable(day,person_id)
 with cte ( DAY, PERSON_ID ) AS(
     SELECT 10, '01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
     SELECT 10, '02' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
     SELECT 10, '04' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
     SELECT 10, '04' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
     SELECT 12, '01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
     SELECT 12, '02' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
     SELECT 12, '03' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
     SELECT 13, '04' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
     SELECT 13, '01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
     SELECT 14, '02' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
     SELECT 14, '01' FROM DUAL)
   select * from cte ;
```

Query#1 (for Oracle 19c and later)

```
   select day, count(person_id) as PEOPLE_LOGGED_EVERYDAY, LISTAGG(distinct person_id,',') WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY person_id) AS PEOPLE
   from yourtable a
   where exists (select 1 from yourtable b where b.day<=a.day and a.person_id=b.person_id
   group by person_id having count(DISTINCT day)=(select COUNT( distinct DAY) from yourtable where day<=a.day))
   group by day;
```

Query#1 (for Oracle 18c and earlier)

```
   select day, count(person_id) as PEOPLE_LOGGED_EVERYDAY, LISTAGG( person_id,',') WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY person_id) AS PEOPLE
   from
   (    
       select distinct day, person_id  
       from yourtable a
       where exists (select 1 from yourtable b where b.day<=a.day and a.person_id=b.person_id
       group by person_id having count(DISTINCT day)=(select COUNT( distinct DAY) from yourtable where day<=a.day))
   )t group by day
```

Output:

| DAY | PEOPLE_LOGGED_EVERYDAY | PEOPLE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | 3 | 01,02,04 |
| 12 | 2 | 01,02 |
| 13 | 1 | 01 |
| 14 | 1 | 01 |

*db<fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=b94cdd4da98f5db9290f64ea779f07eb)*

Comment: This is just a count. What I need is the people who have logged in everyday. I've slightly modified the data to reflect my needs.

Comment: Ok. Let me work on that. I misunderstood.

Comment: @jeiv I have revised my answer. Please check and let me know your feedback.

Comment: Thanks. Would this work if the day was actually a date?

Comment: Nope. Need to change the query.

Comment: @jeiv I have added answer for dates.

Comment: The amended query does not work for the data in the edit.

Comment: @jeiv since the days are not sequentially increased and there are multiple entry for a single person in a day my query won't work as needed. I have added revised answer to address those.

Comment: @jeiv I have shared two query for 19c and for earlier version.

Comment: Thanks! Just one question: in the having clause, there's a reference to 'day'. Would that be a.day or b.day?

Comment: You are most welcome. b.day. Best wishes.

Answer (score 1):

You can use either:

```sql
SELECT DAY,
       COUNT(DISTINCT person_id) AS num_people
FROM   (
  SELECT t.*,
         DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY day)
         - DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY person_id ORDER BY day) AS day_grp
  FROM   table_name t
)
WHERE  day_grp = 0
GROUP BY day
ORDER BY day
```

or `MATCH_RECOGNIZE` to find the successive days:

```sql
SELECT day,
       COUNT(
         DISTINCT
         CASE cls WHEN 'CONSECUTIVE_DAYS' THEN person_id END
       ) AS num_people
FROM   (
  SELECT t.*,
         DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY day) AS day_rank
  FROM   table_name t
)
MATCH_RECOGNIZE(
  PARTITION BY person_id
  ORDER     BY day
  MEASURES
    classifier() AS cls
  ALL ROWS PER MATCH
  PATTERN ( ^ consecutive_days* )
  DEFINE
    consecutive_days AS COALESCE( PREV(day_rank) + 1, 1 ) = day_rank
)
GROUP BY day
ORDER BY day
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name ( DAY, PERSON_ID ) AS
SELECT 1, '01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, '02' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, '03' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, '04' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, '01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, '02' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, '03' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, '01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, '02' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 4, '01' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> | DAY | NUM_PEOPLE |
> | --- | --- |
> | 1 | 4 |
> | 2 | 3 |
> | 3 | 2 |
> | 4 | 1 |

and for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name ( DAY, PERSON_ID ) AS
    SELECT 10, '01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 10, '02' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 10, '04' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 10, '04' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 12, '01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 12, '02' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 12, '03' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 13, '04' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 13, '01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 14, '02' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 14, '01' FROM DUAL
```

Outputs:

> | DAY | NUM_PEOPLE |
> | --- | --- |
> | 10 | 3 |
> | 12 | 2 |
> | 13 | 1 |
> | 14 | 1 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=1c2842a5d6bdce236067883a1785451b)*

Comment: That looks great. Could you please briefly explain how match recognize is working here?

Comment: @jeiv Here is the [`MATCH_RECOGNIZE` documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/dwhsg/sql-pattern-matching-data-warehouses.html). It is just `PARTITION`ing `BY` each `PERSON_ID` then `ORDER`ing `BY` the `day` and then finding `ALL ROWS PER MATCH` that match the `PATTERN` where the `first_day`  is the `MIN(day) OVER ()` (minimum over the full result set) and then the `consecutive_days` are when the `PREV`ious `day` + 1 equals the current `day` .... It will not return any rows that are not matched by the pattern; but you can just read the docs and/or code.

Comment: The query does not work on the data provided in the last edit.

Comment: @jeiv "Does not work" is not a constructive statement as it does not say why you think it does not work. Updated to return all rows.

Answer (score 1):

In Standard SQL, I would approach this by doing the following:

- Enumerate the days for each person.
- Determine the earliest day for each person.
- Filter where the earliest day is "1" and the enumeration equals the days.

Then aggregate:

```
select day, count(*),
       listagg(person_id, ',') within group (order by person_id)
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by person_id order by day) as seqnum,
             min(day) over (partition by person_id) as min_day
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = day and min_day = 1
group by day
order by day;
```

Note only is this simpler than using `match recognize`, but I would guess that the performance would be much better too.

Comment: The query does not work for the sample data in the last edit.